# How does the boolean keyword argument get evaluated in a method?

Tags: python

Hopefully this isn't too dumb/basic, but I think I am missing an essential building block.

I am writing a Python loop to rename files based on OCR results, but want to have the option to keep the original filename. I am new to Python and programming, and have a question to how boolean logic is computed. As background, I understand that True is True, False is False, not True is False, and not False is True.

As for the method/function, it checks to see if the keyword argument for rename = True or False. To do this, I have an if loop that just says "if rename:". By default rename is False. I am unsure why saying "if rename: then dont rename files" does not work, but  writing"if not rename: dont rename files" does work.

I figured out that if I type "if not rename: don't rename files", I get the expected result, but I am not sure why that works.

```
def pnid_rename(file_name, new_name, rename = False):
    if not rename:
        print('Not renaming')
        return
    else:
        print('Renaming ' + file_name)
        os.rename(file_name, str(new_name) + '.png')
        return
```

To me, "if rename" is the same as "if False", as rename = False, so the files should not rename because it is True that False == False. Instead, this triggers the rename loop.

So why do I need 'not'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. What exactly is t working as you expected? Why are you expecting `if False:` to be true? Minor note: an if / else statement is not a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is similar to ask if the variable `rename` is empty or has any value. So if you write:

```
if rename:
        print('Not renaming')
```

Is like if you're asking, if the `rename` variable has any content , so is that true? No, because the value is False, for that reason in that case the function returns Renaming...

And if you write:

```
if not rename:
        print('Not renaming')
```

Is like if you're asking, if the value doesn't have any value, and that is true, because False is similar to say empty. This is a way to understand your logic, but in fact it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I was a bit too tired last night. The if statement will not go to the else condition if the if evaluates as true. And by saying not False, I ensure it is true. Thanks all of the help!